# Speed up image download time

Tags: java, android, image, performance

in my app I'm downloading images I get from an URL. The problem here is that it takes wayy too long. The images are compressed and only 9km big. I'm downloading 50 of them, so let's say 500kByte of images are being downloaded by the app. This should be pretty fast, right? Well, it isn't. I'm sometimes wating for 20 seconds until it's loaded. What is taking so long there? I have a pretty easy way to download the images. Here it is

```
int downloadingImages = getDownloadImageCount();
        System.out.println(downloadingImages);
        if(downloadingImages == 0){
            for(int c = downloadingImages; c < 50; c++){
                try{                    

                        bitmapArr[c]        = getBitmapFromURL(imageURLArr[c]);
                        setDownloadImageCount(50);
                        publishProgress(c);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException f1){
                        Log.v("FileNotFoundException", "Bitmap konnte nicht geladen werden");
                } catch(NullPointerException e){

                } catch (IllegalStateException ie){

                } 
                setDownloadImageCount(50);
            }
        }
```

This is the getBitmapFromUrl function

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        //Downloading the image
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        try{
            //Saving the image to a bitmap and return it
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
            //Catch Exception if file not found
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ffe){
            Log.v("FileNotFoundException", "getBitmapFromURLMethod");
            return null;
        }        
        //Catch Exception if error at input and output
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } 
}
```

I mean, what is taking so long there? How can I increase the speed. I will use cahing for images later, but still... I mean it's 500kbs and takes so long. Why is that?

Comment: don't try to reinvent the wheel: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Put a timestamp as a long on several lines. This can tell you what is taking too long. Connecting with server is also a time consuming process. So make sure connection establishment is taking time or downloading.

Comment: You also can use universal image loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 2):

Its completely natural that it takes a while. For *each* image you load from a URL a new HTTP-request is made (that is a request is sent to the server and it responds).

Thats 50 times the round-trip time over the network (not even including the time it may take the server to respond). You should cache the images locally once you have them retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

The longest step in the process is probably sending a request to the server and waiting for it to respond, and you're repeating this step 50 times. Do you have the ability to modify the server? If so, consider adding an action that lets you download all 50 images at once (perhaps by putting them into a zip file, then unpacking them client-side).

Comment: Any idea how this is done? I havent heard of this before, would be lovely to learn.

Comment: This is a very high-level description to a solution. If you're downloading images to a client app, you likely have a server-client architecture with an MVC or similar architecture server-side (Ruby on Rails, Asp.NET, etc.). You would create a new action on the server, use a third-party library to put the images in a zip file, send the zip file as the action result, and then use a third-party library on your client to unpack the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your InputStream to BufferedInputStream

```
BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(input);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```